# Multiple threads writing to queue, one thread writing to file from queue in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, thread-safety

In a console application, I am reading hundreds of thousands of files (~30 MB each) from the same folder through a *Parallel.ForEach* loop (total size ~150 GB). Each Task of the loop generates an object which I need to write to disk. To avoid generating thousands of output files, I am searching for a way to write all results to the same file.

**Locking threads is not an option** for I need extreme performance and keeping everything in memory is not feasible.

I am not familiar with multitasking except for *Parallel...* loops and I could not find any related SO thread on this topic.

How could I create a queuing system (output order is not important) that threads of the *Parallel.ForEach* loop write their output to, and a background thread taking objects of the queue and appending them to one big file on disk.

**Here is approximately what I have so far**

```
static void ParseData(string directory, MyWriter writer)
{
    string[] files  = Directory.GetFiles(repository);
    Parallel.ForEach(file, files =>
    {
        object obj = GenerateObject(file);
        writer.AddToQueue(obj);
    }
    writer.NothingMoreToAdd = true;
}

class MyWriter : TextWriter
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<object> _queue;

    public bool NothingMoreToAdd {get; set;}

    public MyWriter()
        : base()
    {
         this.NothingMoreToAdd = false;
    }

    public AddToQueue(object obj)
    {
        this._queue.Enqueue(obj);
    }

    // Function to set as asynchronous and to last until this.NothingMoreToAdd is set to true
    public WriteToFile(string file)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            while (!this.NothingMoreToAdd) // until queue is not set to end ...
            {
                if (this._queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    object obj;
                    if (this._queue.TryDequeue(out obj))
                        writer.Write(obj);
                }
                // maybe Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
    }
}
```

A MyWriter object would be instanciated is the Main of the application and its WriteToFile method called in an other thread right after. Then the ParseData method could be launched in the main thread and would end the WriteToFile method when NothingMoreToAdd is set to true.

If you have any suggestions on how this queuing and write to disk could be managed.

Comment: But what is your problem? You already have a multithreaded queuing system...

Comment: He wants to write to a file with multiple threads.  Answer you cannot.. not in any intelligent manner.  However you COULD do it in memory, and then append to file on a timer..

Comment: You want to do Concurrent file (actual disk based) writes *and* want extreme performance? Good luck :P
Like @Trey says you have to do it in memory

Comment: My question is how do I create a unique thread collecting data from the queue and writing to disk.

Comment: basically I'd write it to a concurrentqueu or some such, then on a timer, dump the queue to disk..

Answer (score 0):

Here is something quick and dirty. Ofcourse you can change it to suit your need.
But basically, it accomplishes what you had asked for: Parallelly read multiple files and do something with them and add the result to a queue and persist the results to file

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string outputFile = @"E:\output\file.txt";
            ConcurrentQueue<object> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<object>();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\100D3100\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            bool isCompleted = false;

            Task t1 = new Task(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(file);
                    });
                isCompleted = true;
            });

            t1.Start();

            Task t2 = new Task(() =>
               {
                   object file = new object();

                   while (isCompleted != true)
                   {
                       queue.TryDequeue(out file);
                       if (file != null)
                       {
                           string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(file.ToString());
                           File.AppendAllLines(outputFile, text);
                       }
                   }

                   foreach (var item in queue)
                   {
                       string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(file.ToString());
                       File.AppendAllLines(outputFile, text);
                   }
               });

            t2.Start();

            Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).Wait();
        }
```

Side Note:
Parallel I/O is extremely dependent on hardware, especially when done on disk.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.